# most efficient way to substring path and file out of a string

Tags: python, substring

I am new to python, just wondering what's the best way for python to do the following:

```
file='/var/log/test.txt'
==action==
```

after ==action==, I want to get the path and the file separated like:

```
path='/var/log'
file_name='test.txt'
```

I am not asking how to do this, I am asking the most efficient way to do this using least lines of code.

=EDIT=

What if my file='test.txt' instead of file='/var/log/test.txt'. I would more likely expect:

```
path='.'
path='test.txt'
```

other than

```
path=''
file_name='test.txt'
```

what's the tip for this then?

Comment: As to you actual new question: What's your problem with `path == ""`?  You said it isn't what you expect, but that's not a problem by itself.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I am just curious if there is some existing way I am missing other than do a "if not path" check. But looks like "if not path" check is need in my case. Thanks

Comment: My point is that there is no need to convert an empty directory name to an explicit `"."`.  the empty string will also work in any situation I can imagine, so I don't see a point for additional code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach not if you are trying to do os.dir(path) tho. empty string won't do in this case.

Comment: You probably mean `os.listdir(path)`; you are right, an empty string doesn't seem to work in this case, (while I think it *should* work).

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes, I meant os.listdir(path), but appreciate the discussion very much :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
file = '/var/log/test.txt'
path, file_name = os.path.split(file)
```

yields:

```
path
'/var/log'

file_name
'test.txt'
```

To use [os.path.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.split#os.path.split) requires `import os`. I'd have to think that the Python library is as efficient as it could be.

To respond to the update/edit, if no path is specified and you want the `.` for path, add:

```
if not path: path = '.'
```

I.e.,

```
file = 'test.txt'
path, file_name = os.path.split(file)
if not path: path = '.'
```

gives:

```
path
'.'

file_name
'test.txt'
```

Answer (score 7):

You should look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) of `os.path` , there is a `split` function, for example:

```
path, file_name = os.path.split('/var/log/test/txt')
```